# protocol buffer cannot find symbol newBuilder

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am new to protocol buffer from google so I tried the Java tutorial and everything goes well until I am trying to make an instance of the protocol class. So I tried to make my own proto file but I had the same problem. The problem lies in this piece of code:

```
 AddressBook.Builder address = new AddressBook.newBuilder();
```

On the newBuilder() part I am getting a *cannot find symbol* error. In the comments in the file generated by protoc it says to use the newBuilder() to make an instance of the class and I can't find the problem. Does anyone know the problem and is there a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
new AddressBook.newBuilder();
```

That syntax is half way between a method call and a constructor call. `newBuilder()` is just a static *method*. You just need:

```
AddressBook.Builder builder = AddressBook.newBuilder();
```

Comment: This got me also. Whilst I understand how the message that javac outputs for this type of error makes sense, it could be more useful.